# How to get a list of subfolder names in the external stage and store them in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I have an azure external stage @mystage.
I have folders in it as below:

1. @mystage/nz/atm/INC/2023_02_27
2. @mystage/nz/atm/INC/2023_02_28
3. @mystage/nz/atm/INC/2023_02_30
4. @mystage/nz/drv/INC/2023_02_27
5. @mystage/nz/drv/INC/2023_02_28

I would like to get the names of subfolders under @mystage/nz/atm/INC/ and store them as a separate result and subfolders under @mystage/nz/drv/INC/ in a different table or temporary table.

I tried the following and it works:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE folder_names (name STRING);
list @EXT_STG_ADLS_DEV/atm/INC/;
insert into folder_names(SELECT distinct SPLIT_PART("name",'/', 5) as FOLDER FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))) ;
select * from folder_names;

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: your approach does the job. In what way would you like to improve it?

Comment: @aek I was hoping I could use List command in the insert query and not run it separately prior to insert.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've identified is probably the most efficient way to do it from a Snowflake side, at least that I'm aware of.

You do have this option though:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata

```
INSERT INTO FOLDER_NAMES SELECT distinct metadata$filename FROM @EXT_STG_ADLS_DEV/ATM/INC;
```

You can combine the above with Substring and Regex Functions to extract your folder names. There's efficiencies to be made, I.E Pattern matching on the list command but as these methods end up scanning a the entire path provided, they can be incredibly slow.